# How do I make a filtered immutable?

Tags: redux, react-redux, immutability

Rookie question here. I'm playing around with Redux, but can't figure out how to make this function(I'm deleting completed todos) immutable in an elegant way:
This is from my reducer:

```
case "DELETE_CHECKED_TODOS":
    return state.filter((todo, index) => {
      return !todo.completed
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `state` is a Javascript array (or possibly an Immutable.js list), that looks fine to me.  That will return a new array containing only items that do not have `completed` set, without modifying the old array, so that's a correct example of an immutable update.

For further reference, you may want to read through the [Structuring Reducers - Prerequisite Concepts](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/PrerequisiteConcepts.html) and [Structuring Reducers - Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) sections in the Redux docs, as well as the articles in the [Immutable Data](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md) section of my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).